# How to convert 'MM/DD/YYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM' string to timestamp?

Tags: pyspark

Timestamp comes in the string form '12/22/2018 04:30:00 PM', but I need it into a 24-hour timestamp to match other data.

I tried to do this manually form the sqlContext.read.format to no avail, it converts it to string regardless.

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- Trip ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Trip Start Timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Trip End Timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Trip Seconds: integer (nullable = true)
```

Current:

Trip Start Timestamp = ['12/22/2018 04:30:00 PM'] is a string.

Looking for:

Trip Start Timestamp = ['12/22/2018 016:30:00'] as a timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a similar timestamp string in my program. Below code may work in your case:

```py
df = df.withColumn("new_timestamp",to_timestamp("Trip Start Timestamp","MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"))
```

You can refer the timestamp format: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Proper timestamp format you're looking for is MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS